# Adding Date & Time to Cinnamon panel on Mint

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, applet, main-desktop-panel

I accidentally removed the Time displayed in Cinnamon's system tray on my Linux Mint, and am not sure how to add it back. It doesn't seem to be available among the options in the Applets window (that comes up on choosing "Add applets to the panel"), and there's nothing about the systray display in the "Date & Time" system settings either. How do I get this back on my display?

Answer (score 1):

Steps to add calendar applet to panel:

1. From the **Menu** open the **System Settings** window.
2. In the **Preferences** section, click on **Applets**
3. You can see a list of applets available on alphabetical order. Right-Click on **Calendar** and select **Add to Panel**.

Comment: So it's the calendar applet that displays the time in systray? In that case, I seem to have run into this bug: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=218&t=175478
    Also, when that empty space mentioned is clicked on, I get only this: http://imgur.com/5YQnYFK

Comment: I wasn't aware of this bug. I'm on Fedora 21 with Cinnamon 2.4